# How I can use in asp.net multiple controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following two controllers: `HomeController` and `DocGenController`. The `HomeController` is the default controller in my project. I would like to open with a button-click a function in my `DocGenController`. For example: I created on my page a top-navigation. I used this code to open the `DocGen.cshtml`- page (via the controller `HomeController`): `@Html.ActionLink("Generator", "DocGen", "Home")`.

Ok, now I tried this: `@Html.ActionLink("Add Value", "AddValue", "DocGen", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })` but I get every time this Error: `The resource (/Home/AddValue) can be not found (Error: 404)` .

Why he try to open /Home/AddValue ?!

How can I use my DocGenController?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Add Value", "Home", "DocGen", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" },new {param1=1,param2=2})   action link has many overloads,  the one you are using ,  actionlink('title','controller','action',new{other parameters etc})

Comment: As per your code @Html.ActionLink("Generator", "DocGen", "Home") Home is the controller and DocGen is action. Please swap them and try.

Comment: @user3151766 its not working

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use as : @Html.ActionLink("Generator", "YOUR FUNCTION NAME", "DocGen")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload of Action Link method, as you can see here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

The signature of the simplest method including controller name is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

Which means you need to provide one more object to your call, or one less and use:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName
)
```

So for example: `@Html.ActionLink("Add Value", "AddValue", "DocGen")` should do the job or:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Value", "AddValue", "DocGen", new{}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

within the params object you'll probably want to pass some id or confirguration :)

Comment: @Desperado not really as you have overload of string, string, object, object, which is a perfect match for the arguments provided by OP, just that then "DocGen" is passed as object routeValues. It's easy to debug and check :)

Comment: so yeap, if it was you @Desperado that downvoted... then you're wrong

Comment: @mikus it's not me, please dont revenge on my post im not like that!

Comment: sure, I wouldn't :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can also use a HTML `<a>`-Tag and in the `href` you just put: `href='@Url.Action("AddValue", "DocGen")'`

So the complete `<a>` would be:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("AddValue", "DocGen")' class="btn btn-primary">Add Value</a>
```

Comment: it's also a preferable solution if you need to integrate url within some more complicated structure :)